# SonarQube gives "Use static access with "..DemoEntity_" for "DELETED" error

Tags: java, static, sonarqube

SonarQube produces the following message:

"*Use static access with "com.company.model.DemoEntity_" for "DELETED" error.*"

Actually `Employee` entity extends from `DemoEntity`. So, what is the cause of the error and how to fix it?

```
public class EmployeeCriteriaRequest extends PageableCriteriaRequest {

    @Override
    public List <SearchCriteria> getSearchCriteriaList() {
        final List < SearchCriteria > searchCriteriaList = new ArrayList < > (1);
        searchCriteriaList.add(new SearchCriteria(true,
            SearchCriteria.EQUAL_OPERATION, Employee_.DELETED, false));

        return searchCriteriaList;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a hint, you should access the constant by referencing it where it is defined - which seems to be DeletableEntity_.DELETED . It is preferable to your usage, because you could've defined it in your Employee_ otherwise which then would not match equal criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these good explanations. Actually Employee_ extends DeletableEntity_ and DELETED property is coming from DeletableEntity_.So, I think I should change the code from `Employee_.DELETED` to `DeletableEntity_.DELETED`. Is that true?

Comment: @juwil Any reply please?

Comment: you are right, just change this.

Comment: Perfect!.. Thanks a lot, it fixed my problem. Regards...

Comment: I  just have an issue regarding to this. What is the meaning of the trailing underscore (_) in DeletableEntity_? I sometimes see this for the classes in target class. Why do we use generated class `DeletableEntity_` while we already have `DeletableEntity`?

Comment: The classes with underscores are normally generated meta model classes. They each belong to an corresponding entity class and, as meta model, do not hold data or functionality but field names, constants etc

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made some search on Google using "what is meta model class in Java" phrase, but I cannot reach a brief explanation. So, would you suggest some useful pages for me to understand well this concept. Sorry, I have no experience and knowledge about this issue :(

Comment: maybe this or something similar might give you some information: https://thorben-janssen.com/static-metamodel/  You could seach for jpa static metamodel